# How to assign multiple variable and string in a variable in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, variable-assignment

I want to assign multiple values or string or their combination to a postgresql variable.
What I want to achieve is something like this done in DB2:

```
STRING '('              DELIMITED BY SIZE           
       variable_1       DELIMITED BY SPACE          
       ' '              DELIMITED BY SIZE           
       variable_2                        
                        DELIMITED BY SIZE           
       variable_3       DELIMITED BY SIZE           
       ' ) '            DELIMITED BY SIZE           
       X'10'            DELIMITED BY SIZE           
     INTO    var_string                            
 END-STRING
```

In the same way i have some variables and string which I want to add in a variable "var_string".
Is it possible?

Comment: Are you looking for a simple `concat()`?, e.g.: `var_string := concat(variable_1, ' ', variable_2, variable_3);` Please **[edit]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). (do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Yes CONCAT() it is. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try CONCAT Function

```
 DECLARE var_string varchar;
 var_string:= concat(variable_1, variable_2,variable_3);
```