# How to extract data delimited by some character in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I want to extract data from a passed string delimited by some character(for e.g. csv header data) and store it to different variables.
lets say string: `str='data1,data2,data3,data4'`.
now I want data from string in different variables:

```
var=data1
list=data2
comment=data3
result=data4
```

In DB2 It can be done like this

```
01 RECORD.                                                      
          10 RECORD-A                       PIC X(02)   VALUE SPACES.           
          10 WS-FILLER                      PIC X(01)   VALUE SPACES.           
          10 RECORD-B                       PIC X(05)   VALUE SPACES.           
          10 WS-FILLER                      PIC X(01)   VALUE SPACES.           
          10 RECORD-C                       PIC X(03)   VALUE SPACES.           
          10 WS-FILLER                      PIC X(01)   VALUE SPACES. 
01 INPUT-RECORD                   PIC X(13).

MOVE INPUT-RECORD             TO RECORD
```

where INPUT-RECORD is the input data separated by space. What is the process for postgresql?

Comment: Your example shows COBOL. Do you plan to to use COBOL for accessing Postgresql?

Comment: Isn't that the same as your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48540432/330315) just phrased differently?

Comment: I am trying to make postgresql equivalent of COBOL. Also in previous Question I have data which is to be saved in a string. here I am trying to achieve opposite.

Comment: I can also use split_part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try [regex](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html)

```
SELECT 
    f[1] AS "var"
    , f[2]  AS "list"
    , f[3]  AS "comment"
    , f[4]  AS "result"
FROM regexp_split_to_array('data1,data2,data3,data4', ',+') AS d(f);
```